# Include after_body in toc with bookdown

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I am creating a pdf book, and want to include the after_body header in the toc. I use the following yaml:

```
--- 
author: "name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
geometry: "left=4cm,right=3cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm"
subparagraph: true
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    toc: false
    citation_package: natbib
    includes:
      before_body: frontpage.tex
      after_body: after_body.tex
      in_header: preamble.tex
fontsize: 11pt
linestretch: 1.2
documentclass: book
bibliography: [packages.bib, library.bib]
biblio-style: apalike
link-citations: yes
---
```

In the `after_body.tex` i have the following:

```
\backmatter

\begin{titlepage}
   \LARGE
   \textbf{Enclosed articles I - III}
\end{titlepage}
```

How do I include the "Enclosed articles I - III" in the toc? I create the toc with `\tableofcontents` before `\mainmatter` in the `index.Rmd` file.

Edit: I also noticed that bookdown creates an empty page with a page number after the \titlepage latex environment. This also happens in the frontpage.tex. Is there any way to remove the numbers on these pages?

Comment: Are you looking for `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{whatever}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this by changing the \textbf to \chapter, and include this in the preamble.tex:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{13.6pt} % as requested by fancyhdr's warning

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \if@mainmatter
    \markboth{Chapter \thechapter{}: #1}{}%
  \else
    \markboth{#1}{}%
  \fi
}
```

As taken from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146106/remove-chapter-in-header-of-the-backmatter?rq=1)